# I am unable to parse message-header sent by MailGun to Json

Tags: c#, json, mailgun

```
[
["Received", "by luna.mailgun.net with SMTP mgrt 8734663311733; Fri, 03 May 2013 18:26:27 +0000"], 
["Content-Type", ["multipart/alternative", {"boundary": "eb663d73ae0a4d6c9153cc0aec8b7520"}]], 
["Mime-Version", "1.0"], ["Subject", "Test bounces webhook"], 
["From", "Bob <bob@rs19930.mailgun.org>"], 
["To", "Alice <alice@example.com>"], 
["Message-Id", "<20130503182626.18666.16540@rs19930.mailgun.org>"], 
["List-Unsubscribe", "<mailto:u+na6tmy3ege4tgnldmyytqojqmfsdembyme3tmy3cha4wcndbgaydqyrgoi6wszdpovrhi5dinfzw63tfmv4gs43uomstimdhnvqws3bomnxw2jtuhusteqjgmq6tm@rs19930.mailgun.org>"], 
["X-Mailgun-Sid", "WyIwNzI5MCIsICJhbGljZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsICI2Il0="], 
["X-Mailgun-Variables", "{\"my_var_1\": \"Mailgun Variable #1\", \"my-var-2\": \"awesome\"}"], 
["Date", "Fri, 03 May 2013 18:26:27 +0000"], ["Sender", "bob@rs19930.mailgun.org"]
]
```

I am getting this as a message-header from mailgun. I need to parse this header into json. I have tried `JObject.Parse(message_headers)` and `JArray.Parse(message_headers)`. But it does not work.

When I remove `["X-Mailgun-Variables", "{\"my_var_1\": \"Mailgun Variable #1\", \"my-var-2\": \"awesome\"}"]` this it seems to work.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Exactly. The line you posted is not JSON.

Comment: `JArray.Parse()` works fine for me.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/eLpjof.  If you don't know anything about the structure of the JSON in advance, [`JToken.Parse()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse.htm) is safest.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Mailgun headers are not JSON objects. I ran into this same problem and the way I solved it was to parse out the values I needed and manually convert them to a JSON object.